# Best way to store news article in android?

Tags: android, database, database-schema

I want to save news article in android.
The problem is, that they contain random occurrences of text and image. so I cant really use a SQL database. What could be the most efficient way to do it. Should I use a NoSQL database? If yes then which one ?

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML file.
Create XML according to your news like

```
<news>
    <title>.....</title>
    <img src="image.JPG"></img>
    <message>.....</message>
    .
    .
    .
</news>
```

And use a XML parser to parse XML content to views.